# Excel 2007 VBA MATCH function is not finding a match, but a match does exist in that range?

Tags: excel, function, vba, excel-2007, match

In Excel 2007 VBA - My Match statement below is not finding the text.  It is there, and in the specified range.  I'm not getting unusual errors.  It's just not being found.  Here is the full text in cell AZ65- More items related to "Cricut Shoulder Bag"

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match("More items related to*", Range("az1:ba1000"))) Then
removeSomeRows = Application.Match("More items related to*", Range("az1:ba1000"))
Range("az" & removeSomeRows & ":" & "bz1000").ClearContents
End If
```

On the worksheet this also isn't working

```
=MATCH("More items related to*",AZ1:Ba1000)
```

Comment: `Match()` can't be used on a multi-column range like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use MatchType of 0 to use wild card characters (* or ?) see: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx

Use `Application.Match("More items related to*", Range("AZ1:AZ1000"), 0)`

Comment: I added the 0 and changed it to matching in 1 column and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could also use this:

```
Dim rng as Range

For Each rng in ActiveSheet.Range("AZ1:BA1000")
    If InStr(1, "More items related to", rng) <> 0 Then
        rng.ClearContents
    End If
Next
```